# Git push to remote gives "Network is unreachable" error (Windows)

Tags: git, amazon-ec2, ssh, dokku

I have an app deployed to dokku running on an ec2 ubuntu instance. I have the `.pem` key of the instance and I'm able to connect to it and, apparently, successfully add the remote to git. However, whenever I try to push to the remote it gives me the following error:

```
ssh: connect to host address.of.the.host port 22: Network is unreachable
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Here are the steps that I followed so far:

- Downloaded the `.pem` file to the folder of the project and set the necessary permissions
- Ran the command `ssh-add key-file-name.pem`, which returned `Identity added: key-file-name.pem (key-file-name.pem)`
- Ran `type C:\Users\Myself\.ssh\id_rsa.pub | ssh -i "C:\Users\Myself\Documents\project_name\key-file-name.pem" ubuntu@ec2-<ip-address>.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com sudo dokku ssh-keys:add my-key`, which returned `SHA256:<key>`
- Ran `git remote add prod dokku@address.of.the.host:app-name`
- Ran `git remote --verbose` and confirmed that the remote was added (fetch and push)
- Ran `git push prod master`, which returned the "Network is unreachable" error

I know very little about this stuff. I'm only trying to update the app with some changes that I've made to the code, so I really appreciate anyone that could help.

Comment: That's a networking problem right there, not a git problem. If you are using ssh as a transport, can you try opening an ssh session (even if you are forcefully logged out)? if ssh by itself is not able to connect, git won't br able to either. Side note: please, replace the screenshot for text in the question.

Comment: Hi @eftshift0! Yes, I'm able to open an ssh session without being logged out, no problem with that. The error only occurs when I try to push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I figured out what the problem was (as always, right after exposing it, but ok).

I was adding the romote using the host name (`dokku@address.of.the.host:app-name`). Once I changed it to the ip (public IPv4) it worked...

This ip can be found at your aws panel > Services > EC2 > Instances > click on the instance's ID > IPv4 public address.